# failed loading cafile stream while installing composer. How to change the path of CA file?

Tags: php, installation, path, composer-php, ca

I tried to install composer. In official website there are 4 commands I should input into terminal to install that. The fisrt one:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

While installing composer I got these errors:

```
failed loading cafile stream: `C:\Users\admin\Downloads\cacert.pem" in Command line code on line 1
copy(): Failed to enable crypto in Command line code on line 1
copy(https://getcomposer.org/installer): Failed to open stream: operation failed in Command line code on line 1
```

I am aware I should write something in php.ini
Here's the piece of my php.ini code:

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\apache\bin\cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile = "C:\xampp\apache\bin\cacert.pem"
```

Anyway it does not work. And what is the weirdest is a contradiction between the path in my code of php.ini and the path in error text. The file cacert.pem is present in the necessary directory and it is absent in Downloads. How to change the path of CA file to avoid this error?

Comment: What directory are you current in when you are running this?

Comment: The correct directory - C:\xampp\apache\bin\cacert.pem

Comment: Is that the correct directory to be installing composer into?

Comment: As I can understand it should be installed in C:\xampp\htdocs

Comment: But I have seen under another question that for CA certificate the directory can be another.